# Why is it true that $\int _0^x\left(F_y\left(s\right)-G_y\left(3s\right)\right)ds=F\left(x\right)-\frac{1}{3}G\left(x\right)$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Note that the functions F and G only have one variable ($F,\:G:\:\mathbb{R}\:\rightarrow \:\mathbb{R}$), and that we initially got

$$u\left(x,y\right)=F\left(x+y\right)+G\left(3x-y\right)$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\left(x,y\right)=\frac{\partial \:F}{\partial \:y}\left(x+y\right)-\frac{\partial \:G}{\partial \:y}\left(3x-y\right)$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\left(x,0\right)=\frac{\partial \:F}{\partial \:y}\left(x\right)-\frac{\partial \:G}{\partial \:y}\left(3x\right)$$

Where $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\left(x,0\right)=0$ by our initial conditions given

So we have

$$\frac{\partial \:\:F}{\partial \:\:y}\left(x\right)-\frac{\partial \:\:G}{\partial \:\:y}\left(3x\right)=0$$

And we now take this integral which gives us

$$\int _0^x\left(\frac{\partial \:F}{\partial \:y}\left(s\right)-\frac{\partial \:G}{\partial \:y}\left(3s\right)\right)ds=\int _0^x0\:ds$$

Which essentially gives us

$$F\left(x\right)-\frac{1}{3}G\left(x\right)=C$$

I don't understand why we are getting this result if we calculate the integral, and also why the right side is equal to a constant C (it should be 0 as it is a bounded integral on 0)

The other conditions which might be useful are: $u\left(x,0\right)=3x^2$ and $\frac{\partial ^2ũ}{\partial \xi \partial \eta }=0$ for $\xi =x+y,\:\eta =3x-y$ and $ũ\left(\xi ,\eta \right)=F\left(\xi \right)+G\left(\eta \right)$

Comment: Just an advice, you probably want to keep the function and its parameters next to each other so instead of writing $\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y}(s)$ write $\dfrac{\partial G(s)}{\partial y}$ or $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}G(s)$

Comment: Tbh the way I wrote is how we write it at our university, I thought it's a common way to write it

Comment: You can use whatever notation you want to to use. For me this is the first time i see it written this way. For example with $\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y}(3x-y)$ it looks like you multiply $\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y}$ with (3x-y), but ultimately it's your decision.

Comment: Im gonna try to remember it for the next time. I once wrote something like $u_x$ here and people were asking me what it means, although I thought that it was a common way to write $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u$. Because that's the notation we are using at our university if dealing with ODE/PDE

Comment: You say you $F$ and $G$ are functions of one variable. Please write this down formally. $F(x+y)$ is not that. Moreover $\int_0^x\dfrac{\partial F(y)}{\partial y}dy\neq F(x)$

Comment: What I rather meant was that F and G is from R to R, I've edited it the way I wanted it originally meant

Comment: $u_x$ is definitely standard notation. When in doubt you can just [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#Notation) and then still decide to not use their notation. $f_{xyz...\text{etc.}}$ is like $u_{xyz...\text{etc.}}$. Most of the time the general function used for PDEs is $u$.

Comment: Does $y$ depend on $x$?

Comment: We originally have $u\left(x,y\right)=ũ\left(\xi ,\eta \right)=F\left(\xi \right)+G\left(\eta \right)=F\left(x+y\right)+G\left(3x-y\right)$, thus if we want to calculate $u_y$ expressed with the help of F and G, we are doing it like I did.

Comment: No, it does not depend on x

Comment: Right, now because we have the condition given that $u_y\left(x,\:0\right)=0$, we get that $F'\left(x\right)-G'\left(3x\right)=0$. Why don't we use partials on the right-side?

Comment: But wouldn't they be zero anyways? You differentiate a function of $x$ wrt. $y$.

Comment: Because $F$ and $G$ are single-variable functions.  The chain rule for compositions of the form $$\mathbb{R}^2 \xrightarrow{\phi} \mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb{R}$$ is $$\frac{\partial (f\circ \phi)}{\partial y} = (f'\circ\phi)\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}$$

Comment: No, you already have differentiated F and G by y, and **then** you put y=0 which results in only x left. E,g, $H\left(x+y\right)=\left(x+y\right)e^{x+y}$, then $H_y\left(x+y\right)=\left(1+x+y\right)e^{x+y}$ and $H_y\left(x\right)=\left(1+x\right)e^x$

Comment: Oh okay, i missed that! My bad.

Comment: In that case it is, because $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}F\left(x+y\right)=F_y\left(x+y\right)\cdot \frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(x+y\right)=F_y\left(x+y\right)$

Comment: Okay.  Suppose $F(t) = 5t$.  What is $F_y$? My point is that notation is 80% the problem here, and using $F'$ instead of $F_y$ (which is arguably nonsense) will get you almost all the way to your answer.

Comment: That's a wonderful question, and I absolutely don't have an idea. If I had to guess I'd say 0, but on the other hand, the main question here is what is our y in the first place, compared to t. Is it the same? So why do we even bother to differentiate between x and y in the problem I've presented?

Comment: I think $F_y = \frac{d}{dy}\big(5x + 5y) = 5$

Comment: So we don't know?

Comment: But why should it be nonsense? Let's say $G\left(3x-y\right)=3x-y$, then $G_x\left(3x-y\right)=3$ and $G_y\left(3x-y\right)=-1$. So it's obvious that $G_x$ and $G_y$ describe something different, and we can't just swipe it "under one variable because it's all the same"

Comment: I can't repeat often enough that that's not what $G_x$ and $G_y$ refer to.  You are talking about $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (G(3x-y)) = 3$ which is absolutely not $G_x(3x-y)$ (the former makes sense, the latter makes no sense unless you define $G_x = G'$, but in that case, it's not what you want).

Comment: Here's another example, to check that you understand the notation.  Suppose $f(x,y) = 2x + 5y$.  Then $$f_x(x,y) = 2 = f_x(y,x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f(x,y)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(f(y,x)) \\ f_y(x,y) = 5 = f_y(y,x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(f(x,y)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f(y,x))$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation seems to be the main issue.  Your work should be written as

> Note that the functions F and G only have one variable ($F,\:G:\:\mathbb{R}\:\rightarrow \:\mathbb{R}$), and that we initially got
>
> $$u\left(x,y\right)=F\left(x+y\right)+G\left(3x-y\right)$$
>
> $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\left(x,y\right)=F'(x+y)-G'(3x-y)$$
>
> $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\left(x,0\right)=F'(x)-G'(3x)$$
>
> Where $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\left(x,0\right)=0$ by our initial conditions given
>
> So we have
>
> $$F'(x)-G'(3x)=0$$
>
> And we now take this integral which gives us
>
> $$\int _0^x\left(F'(s)-G'(3s)\right)ds=\int _0^x0\:ds$$
>
> Which essentially gives us
>
> $$F\left(x\right)-\frac{1}{3}G\left(3x\right)=C$$

The last step follows by the fundamental theorem of calculus.  In particular, we have
$$0 = \int_0^x 0\,ds = \int_0^x (F'(s)-G'(3s))\,ds = \left(F(x)-\frac{1}{3}G(3x)\right)- \left(F(0)-\frac{1}{3}G(0)\right)$$
so that $$F(x)-\frac{1}{3}G(3x) = F(0)-\frac{1}{3}G(0) = C$$

Comment: Well done, beat me to it.  Formatting takes for freaking ever.